# 4 Javascript commands execute simultaneously when 1 button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, themes

I have four html elements on a page that are each meant to execute a different setTheme JS command when clicked. However, when I click one, nothing happens. I'm pretty sure they all execute at the same time, and because they're all basically the same code, they cancel each other out and it reverts back to the default theme, which means I see nothing. However, I could be wrong. How do I fix this?

A note about this code: I couldn't figure this out at first, so I looked online but couldn't find anything, so I modified some code meant for the toggleTheme function, not the setTheme function. If that's the problem, I don't know how to solve it but it might help you.

This is the code for one of them (the others are similar, but with, for example, 'theme-light-purple' replaced by 'theme-light-blue' or 'theme-dark-blue'. 'theme-dark-purple' is the default.):

```
<button id="switch-light-purple" onclick="setTheme()">Light Purple</button>
    
    <script>
        // function to set a given theme/color-scheme
        function setTheme(themeName) {
            localStorage.setItem('theme', themeName);
            document.documentElement.className = themeName;
        }

        // function to set theme
        function setTheme() {
                setTheme('theme-light-purple');
        }

        // Immediately invoked function to set the theme on initial load
        (function () {
            if (localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'theme-light-purple') {
                setTheme('theme-light-purple');
            } else {
                setTheme('theme-dark-purple');
            }
        })();
    </script>
```

Comment: `Uncaught InternalError: too much recursion` What exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The second `setTheme` function definition will overwrite the first. Why do you have two functions named the same?

Comment: Why there are 2 `setTheme` function?

Comment: Why not change the second `setTheme` name to something like `resetTheme` as it doesn't take any params?

Comment: I'm trying to change the color scheme of my site a different way with each button. I have two setTheme functions because the first one is to define where to find the documentElement and the second is to execute the command. Should I combine them into one command?

Comment: added an answer to combine two functions into one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button id="switch-light-purple" onclick="setTheme('theme-light-purple-dark')">Light Purple</button>

<script>
  // function to set a given theme/color-scheme
  function setTheme(themeName) {
    localStorage.setItem('theme', themeName);
    document.documentElement.className = themeName;
  }

  // Immediately invoked function to set the theme on initial load
  (function () {
    if (localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'theme-light-purple') {
      setTheme('theme-light-purple');
    } else {
      setTheme('theme-dark-purple');
    }
  })();
</script>
```

You don't need to write 2 functions.

Comment: Just a side note: this is going to work for the given scenario, because currently the user can switch between two themes but if in the future a third one is added you might actually need to handle a "default case" for `setTheme()`

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should have your code

```
function setTheme(themeName = 'theme-light-purple') {
    localStorage.setItem('theme', themeName);
    document.documentElement.className = themeName;
}
```

Here, you are providing a default value to your first parameter in case you want to call the `setTheme` function without any parameters like this `setTheme()`

So, if you call `setTheme()` it automatically means you are calling `setTheme('theme-light-purple')`

[Here's the official documentation for default parameters if you want to go through.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

Answer (score 0):

If you want `setTheme()` to behave differently whether it receives or not an argument (and if I understood what you want to achieve), you need to replace:

```js
// function to set a given theme/color-scheme
function setTheme(themeName) {
  localStorage.setItem('theme', themeName);
  document.documentElement.className = themeName;
}

// function to set theme
function setTheme() {
  setTheme('theme-light-purple');
}
```

with:

```js
// function to set a given theme/color-scheme or a default one if none is provided
function setTheme(themeName) {
  const chosenTheme = themeName ? themeName : 'theme-light-purple';

  localStorage.setItem('theme', chosenTheme);
  document.documentElement.className = chosenTheme;
}
```

[EDIT] Following the comment, I am adding a *partial* demo; unfortunately the code snippet cannot access `window.localStorage` therefore the storing to and retrieving from localStorage of the theme cannot be demonstrated here:

```css
/* theme default */

html.theme-default body {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #efefef;
}

html.theme-default button {
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #333;
}

html.theme-default p {
  border: 1px dashed #333;
  color: #333;
}


/* theme red */

html.theme-red body {
  color: #300;
  background-color: #ffefef;
}

html.theme-red button {
  border: 2px solid #c00;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #300;
}

html.theme-red p {
  border: 1px dashed #c00;
  color: #300;
}


/* theme green */

html.theme-green body {
  color: #030;
  background-color: #efffef;
}

html.theme-green button {
  border: 2px solid #0c0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #030;
}

html.theme-green p {
  border: 1px dashed #0c0;
  color: #030;
}


/* theme blue */

html.theme-blue body {
  color: #003;
  background-color: #efefff;
}

html.theme-blue button {
  border: 2px solid #00c;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #003;
}

html.theme-blue p {
  border: 1px dashed #00c;
  color: #003;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="switch-default" onclick="setTheme()">default (grey)</button>
  <button id="switch-red" onclick="setTheme('theme-red')">red</button>
  <button id="switch-green" onclick="setTheme('theme-green')">green</button>
  <button id="switch-blue" onclick="setTheme('theme-blue')">blue</button>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit consecutor amet</p>

  <script>
    function setTheme(themeName) {
      const chosenTheme = themeName ? themeName : 'theme-default';

      // window.localStorage.setItem('theme', chosenTheme); // this line is commented as the code snippet has no access to localStorage
      document.documentElement.className = chosenTheme;
    }

    // Immediately invoked function to set the theme on initial load
    (function() {
      /* the following lines are commented as the code snippet has no access to localStorage
      const storedTheme = window.localStorage.getItem('theme') || null;

      if (storedTheme) {
        setTheme(storedTheme);
      } else {
        setTheme();
      }
      */
      
      setTheme() // this line should be deleted in the actual code
    })();
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: So I tried your code, and at first I thought it worked well (it automatically loaded the default theme, which it wasn't doing before), but when I clicked the buttons, the theme turned into 'theme-light-blue', the last theme of the four I have listed. I'm not sure why that is, as all four elements are completely separate from each other.

Comment: @EmrysMayell unfortunately the code snippet cannot access `window.localStorage` therefore that functionality cannot be tested or demonstrated here. Anyway I drafted a quick _partial_ demo for your reference.

Comment: @EmrysMayell here I replicated the demo adding a class to somehow simulate (in a _very_ approximate way) `window.localStorage`: https://jsfiddle.net/k4fs6ume/